# Connection failing to RDS endpoint

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I created an AWS RDS MySQL database instance, tested the connection but keeps failing the connection test "unable to connect to localhost":

[image: mysqlworkbench]

That doesn't make sense because I'm not trying the connection to localhost, I'm trying it to the RDS endpoint which I replaced the default localhost with.

My endpoint public accessibility is enabled:

[image: pb]

And traffic on the rules is pretty much open:

[image: sg]

[image: ob]

VPC attributes DNS hostnames and DNS resolution are also enabled by default:

[image: vpc]

And since it's a default VPC, all default subnets are public subnets and will have a route to a [default gateway (IPv4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html).

[image: gateway]

[image: routes]

I also tried this with and without `useSSL=0` parameter, since I heard the 8.0.27 MySQL workbench has a bug with SSL. It doesn't seem to be related to this issue though.

Comment: Did you enable the VPC attributes DNS hostnames and DNS resolution? Does the subnet have Internet Gateway?

Comment: @RegisterSole yes, please check my updated post

Comment: Looks like the error comes from mysql itself, I wonder if the user you are trying to use to connect is the correct one and/or if the user `root` has permissions to connect from any host.

Comment: @Augusto i also installed MySQL workbench on another machine to rule out machine specific issue and still getting same error

Comment: Yep 100%. When an RDS instance is created, one has to provide a [*master username*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html). By default that username is `admin` but it could be anything else. When mysql is installed on a VM, the root user is only allowed to connect via a socket, not via the network, so the test you mentioned probably failed for a different reason. Check this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_CommonTasks.Connect.html), which explains how to get the master user for an RDS instance.

Comment: @Augusto ugh its still not working despite using a new master username, e.g. admin

Comment: @Augusto figured it out! posted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because an inbound rule has to be created, either on your individual IP, or **ALL traffic** if you wish to keep it flexible

[Create Inbound Security Group](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#CreateSecurityGroup:): The default VPC security group created will not accept internal (inbound) connections when you try connecting to the endpoint in MySQL client. Therefore, you need to create an inbound security group as well as follows:
a.  Search and select EC2 service
b.  By default, you should land on the security group page. You can also navigate to the Security Groups page from the left-hand menu under “Network & Security”
c.  Click “Create Security Group”
d.  Fill out the basic details and then create the inbound rules
e.  Create security group

[image: sg creation]

Now associate the created security group with the RDS database instance

Go back/search for RDS service and click on the database instance identifier again and Click Modify
Find the “Connectivity” module.
a.  Deselect the “Default” security group
b.  Search for and select the security group you created earlier

[image: connectivity]

c.  Click Continue
d.  Review the changes in the “Summary of Modifications”, and from “Scheduling of Modifications”, choose “Apply Immediately” and click “Modify DB Instance”